# How to cancel and replace Kotlin Coroutine Call

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am experimenting with Kotlin Coroutines in my current Android application.

I have a use case where a user can search for text using a remote RestFul API.

What I would like to achieve is as follows:-

1). The use types "ABC" and I start my Remote API within this search string

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  repository.searchAPI(searchString)
}
```

2). The user now types more so that my search string is now "ABCXYZ"

I now wish to cancel the initial search of "ABC" and replace it with a the new search string of "ABCXYZ"

I thought I could use this code...

```
viewModelScope.launch {

  if (isActive) {
    this.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
  }

  repository.searchAPI(searchString)
}
```

However this cancels the entire process

How can I achieve the desired result of replacing a currently executing search with the most recent search string?

Comment: you might wanna use `Flow`s for this case

Comment: this also might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/62327188/1731626

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store your search job in the view model's field and cancel it on the new search. It will be something like this:

```
var searchJob: Job? = null
...
searchJob?.cancel()
searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
  repository.searchAPI(searchString)
}
```

Comment: Additionally: If the function is called inside a controller that starts a new thread with every incoming call, make sure to make `searchJob` access synchronised.

Comment: It gives me this error some times, ```kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelled}```

Comment: Keep in mind, that `.cancel()` doesn't actually cancel your Job. It just changes Job's status to `Cancelled`. So, if inside `.searchAPI()` call you don't check if coroutine context is still active, you will have 2 search processes running.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel your coroutine call as follow

```
 val job =viewModelScope.launch {
      repository.searchAPI(searchString)
    }
job.cancel() // cancels the job
```